Insert text into a slide with the javascript office add-ins API doesn't work
Anyone can help me with the javascript office add-ins API for powerpoint?
I am trying to add a sideload add-in that just has a button to some text on a slide. And this works perfectly fine when I put a text example in a variable manually but when I retrieve this text from an API it doesn't work although I am sure the text fetching from the API works because I can print it on the console. I get a cors and load failed error
I tried everything I found online but since the project is created automatically, it is very hard to manage. I used this tutorial and modified the code
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/powerpoint-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator
I am trying to find a way to make the API call work. From the API side everything works fine but still I am not getting the response

You say "it doesn't work" but you never quite say what exactly isn't working. Do you get garbled data? No data at all? Please explain. Also, show your code.

Is the API is hosted locally or it's some other API? I am using the functionality (adding text using API),, and it works,, if you can share an API, i can try to test, :).. also try Axios or fetch for the API call, and it should work.
